# Client vs. Server terminology

Tags: networking

I always get these two terms confused. How do you determine which side is the server and which side is the client? Is it determined by whether it's sending or receiving data? (Assuming the connection goes one-way)

Thank you,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), it's determined by the side that initiated the connection. The client initiates a connection, and the server listens for and accepts a connection. Once connected, data can flow both ways.

Answer (score 10):

Definitions:

[Server-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side) refers to operations that are performed by the server in a client–server relationship in computer networking. Typically, a server is a software program, such as a web server, that runs on a remote server, reachable from a user's local computer or workstation.

[Client-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side) refers to operations that are performed by the client in a client–server relationship in a computer network. Typically, a client is a computer application, such as a web browser, that runs on a user's local computer or workstation and connects to a server as necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot more instances of one side of the connection than the other, the one with more instances is the client.

If one side stays running a lot longer than the other, the one that stays up longer is the server.